# TranslateAnimation с СОХРАНЕНИЕМ РАЗМЕРА после ScalEAnimation

Tags: java, android, изображения, анимация, animate

Добрый день.
Есть необходимость сделать анимацию для imageview.
Сначала картинка появляется посередине, затем тут же уменьшается в размерах (наполовину) и сразу же после этого уезжает наверх(padding 10 от верха экрана).
Проблема в том, что анимация "отъезда" наверх делается с изначальным размером картинки, а мне нужно, чтобы размер сохранился после scaleAnimation. Подскажите, пожалуйста: как мне это сделать?

**scaleAnimation.xml**

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:fromXScale="1"
android:toXScale="0.5"
android:fromYScale="1"
android:toYScale="0.5"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="1000"
android:fillAfter="true"
```

**onCreate Activity:**

```
 pasword_layout_image_splash.startAnimation(scale); //первая анимация Scale


    handler = new Handler();        // затем задержка на 1,5 секунды и выполнение движения наверх
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            scale.setFillAfter(true);
            int[] coords = {0,0};
            pasword_layout_image_splash.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
            int y = coords[1];
            TranslateAnimation toTop = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, ((-y) - 10));
            toTop.setDuration(700);
            toTop.setFillAfter(true);
            pasword_layout_image_splash.startAnimation(toTop);
        }
    }, 1500);
```

Пробовал использовать getLayoutParams().width = 125; в handler - эффекта не дало, размер не менялся. 
Также, как видно из кода, пытался вызвать scale.setFillAfter(true); в самом handler - тоже эффекта не дало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

Создать `set` из нескольких анимаций с задержкой исполнения второй примерно так:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:toXScale="0.5"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toYScale="0.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1000"/>
    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:startOffset="2500"
        android:toYDelta="-1000"/>
</set>
```

Во второй анимации подставьте нужные вам значения.

Файл с описанием анимации поместите в `res/anim`

Запускайте так:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CONTEXT, animResId);
YOURS_VIEW.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ! Как раз начал понимать, как это сделать - и тут Ваш ответ. Остался один момент: в конце анимации image возвращается в свой первоначальный размер. Как я понимаю, это атрибуты ** android:fillAfter="true"
  android:fillBefore="false"
  android:fillEnabled="true" ** Но,установив их, все равно image в конце анимации имеет свой размер. Могли бы помочь исправить это?

Comment: Хмм, хотя программно scale.setFillAfter(true); все работает. А в xml - не работает. В общем, я разобрался. Благодарю за ответ!